# Trying to convert this date format "'year|month" into name of Month using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm facing an issue when trying to convert a specific date format into name of month. Supermetrics, an addon for Google Spreadsheets, returns date formats like the following: "2016|08", etc.

I have tried several solutions from the documentation without any luck. Any solutions or specific functions that I should look for?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid unnecessary calculations, it's assumed that the year doesn't matter, if it does, replace `1900` by `LEFT(A1,4)`.

## Alternative 1

```
=Date(1900,Right(A1,2),1) and apply MMMM as custom format
```

If A1 value is `2016|08` the result value will 1/08/1900 (assuming that the locale short date format is dd/mm/yyyy) but `August` will be displayed.

## Alternative 2

```
=TEXT(Date(1900,Right(A1,2),1),"MMMM")
```

If A1 value is `2016|08` the result value will be `August`.